# How to prevent highlighting when using ‘xref-pop-marker-stack’

Tags: highlighting, xref

I was using [dumb-jump](https://github.com/jacktasia/dumb-jump) to get back from jump definition's location. I started to get following message:

```
‘dumb-jump-back’ is an obsolete command (as of 2020-06-26); 
‘dumb-jump-back’ has been obsoleted by ‘xref-pop-marker-stack’.
```

---

When I do `elpy-goto-definition` jump definition's line is not highlighted, so if possible, I want same behavior when I jump back.

Instead of ‘dumb-jump-back’ , when I use `xref-pop-marker-stack` it jumps back but it highlights the jumped line, is it possible to prevent the highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize `xref-after-return-hook` and remove `xref-pulse-momentarily` from it.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: `M-x customize-variable`.